# How do you write a poem where plain descriptions later are proven to be plainly wrong?

Tags: poetry

> The land was unsullied
>
> Green grass to the horizon
>
> Teeming with life
>
> ...
>
> The land was sullied
>
> Green grass no more
>
> There is only death

Sorry for this extremely simple example, but I am wondering how you can do this if you only plainly describe something in a poem without using the I pronoun or any observer for that matter. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You are using a third person omniscient point of view, like an imaginary god or angel describing a scene. It's a non-material observer, but still an observer. What more precisely are you looking for?

Comment: It seems like your example is doing exactly what you're describing... what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to give the reader an indication that what is described is false, without explaining it, you could do this by bringing up an obvious false statement that shows the reader that the others must also be false statements.

A small example from a song:

> She writes her mother a card home every week.
>
> How are you?
>
> I'm fine
>
> I think of you every day.
>
> The sun rises in the west.

Everyone knows that the last sentence is not true. And therefore one also knows (or at least believes) that the rest is not true either.

I hope this helps you.